# Distance from point to a line

Tags: linear-algebra

Write a formula for distance from a point to a line. Then count a distance from point $P_1(1,2,4)$ to line $l$, along which intersects the two planes $x+y-2z=1$ and $x+3y-z=4$.

I did a matrix

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&-2&1\\
      1&3&1&4\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

then transformed it to
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&0&-3,5&-0,5\\
      0&1&1,5&1,5\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

but completly don't know what to do next.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the intersection line of this two planes can we get as follows:
mltiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the second we get
$$2y+z=3$$ or
$$y=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{z}{2}$$ Setting $$z=2t$$ we get the line
$$x=-\frac{1}{2}+5t$$
$$y=\frac{3}{2}-t$$
$$z=2t$$ and $t$ is a real number
see here for the distance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line
it is the last formula at this page